# What function (or functions) can I use to pass worksheet title to a reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a number of cells on a worksheet that reference another worksheet. Pretty straight forward except I have to type the name of each worksheet in each formula which is becoming monotonous. What I would like to know is if I can pass that information via formula to the reference.

So currently I use this kind of reference "=+'Worksheet 1'!$B$8" which say returns 98%

Would like something like to do is use a function in place of putting the 'Worksheet 1' since the data referenced is in the same location for every sheet. I can list the worksheet names and use that as the argument base for the function call but I don't know how to make it work in a reference call.

Comment: Three approaches come to mind. 1) Use a placeholder and then do a find and replace.  2) Store the name in a cell and then use the INDIRECT function to convert a string containing a reference to that cell into a complete cell reference (probably more work than just entering the text in the formula).  3) Use the clipboard to hold the name and paste as needed.

Comment: I just reread my question and I realize I was stuttering. Sorry for the miss-communication.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. I do the copy paste now but am looking to populate my summary sheet with a function. I have a series of columns that reference the data on those other sheets like the 'Worksheet 1' and the name changes for each sheet which is a fairly random name. Is there a function that will reference the worksheet label (tab descriptor) to use in a reference call or a function that will pull the text from a list of worksheet labels in the summary sheet. Go from =+'Worksheet 1'!$B$8 to  =+magicfunction(cell ref)!$B$8. Then I can type label once populate multiple references.

Comment: HOLD THE PHONE. You totally answered my question with the =indirect function. That works like a HOT HOT damn. Thank you for the help and for reading through my poor panicked rumblings in my initial question.

Comment: I was looking for an example but couldn't lay my hands on it.  Check out the CELL function: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-b98b713d-d3de-4148-829f-80c886af6410?CorrelationId=64ca61cf-8146-4fcb-a642-218b48c6e231&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.  It allows you to retrieve all kinds of meta data.  "filename" includes the filename and worksheet name, which can be extracted with text functions.  To use it, you would need something like a table with a reference cell in each workbook, plus the extracted workbook name.  Reference/lookup the table in an INDIRECT function.

Comment: @fixer1234 The idea [using `=CELL` is good](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-sheet-name-only). But it only works with saved files. Newly, unsaved files fail with this solution. Anyway, maybe it's enough for the OP

Comment: Somewhat related, if you ever want a formula to return the name of the sheet it's in, you can create a named range (called, say, SheetName) and have it refer to `=GET.CELL(62, INDIRECT("A1"))`

Comment: @fixer1234 you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_, This question was kind of broad.  I offered some hints to get the OP started and the OP ran with it for a solution.  My brain is too fried to put together a good answer on this one.  I'm wondering if it might better be closed (OP hasn't returned in over 3 yrs.).  If you want to take a shot at answering, go for it.  :-)

Comment: IMHO, a good hint is much better than direct answers. [ :

Answer (score 1):

Use INDIRECT()

Assuming the worksheet name is in cell A1, this should do it:

```
=indirect("'"&A1&"'!"&$B$8")
```

INDIRECT builds a cell reference from text and formulas.  The ampersands concatenate the pieces together.

*Note: the OP indicates in a comment that that this was the solution used:
"You totally answered my question with the =indirect function".*